# Webpack2 Lazy Loading multiple modules

Tags: lazy-loading, webpack-2

I need to lazy load multiple files at the same time.

Would be nice to lazy load a modul + its language files

Is there something possible like this?

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "chart.js" */ ['chart.js','chart.de.js']).then((Chart, Chart2) => { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here https://survivejs.com/webpack/building/code-splitting/#dynamic-import

```
Promise.all([
  import("lunr"),
  import("../search_index.json"),
]).then(([lunr, search]) => {
  return {
    index: lunr.Index.load(search.index),
    lines: search.lines,
  };
});
```